# Make changes in many google sheets by list of links

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the script with which I can change the format of cells in documents in a specific folder. Tell me, how can I modify the script to make these changes according to the list of links? All files are in different folders.

[image]

```
function Removed_spaces() {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder_ID").getFiles()
while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openById(file.getId()).getSheets();
    for ( var i = 0 ; i<3 ; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];
    
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var range = sheet.getRange('A1:X'+lastRow);
    range.setNumberFormat("@");


}
}
}
```

I try to add part from other script... But in vain

```
function Removed_spaces() {
  const sheetName = "111";
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const fileIds = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce((ar, [a]) => {
    if ((/^https:\/\/docs.google.com\/spreadsheets\/d/).test(a)) ar.push(a.split("/")[5]);
    return ar;
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Those urls look incomplete so there useless.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes from list of ids

```
function makeChangesFromIdList() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
  let arr = [];
  while(files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    arr.push(file.getId());
  }
  arr.forEach(id => {
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(id).getSheets().filter((_,i) => i < 3).filter(e => e).forEach(sh => {
      sh.getRange('A1:X' + sh.getLastRow()).setNumberFormat("@")
    })
  })
}
```